# .include? is not triggered when reading a txt file

Tags: ruby, search, ternary-operator

I am under the impression that the following code **should** return either the search item `word` or the message `no match` - as indicated by the ternary operator.  I can't diagnose where/why include? method doesn't work.

```
class Foo

def initialize(word)
    @word=word
end

def file_open
    IO.foreach('some_file.txt') do |line|
        line.include?(@word) ? "#{@word}" : "no match"
    end
end

end

print "search for: "
input = gets.chomp.downcase

x = Foo.new(input)
puts x.file_open
```

The `input` exists in `some_file.txt`. My ternary operator syntax is also correct. IO reads the text fine (I also tried File.open() and had the same problem). So I must be making a mistake with my `include?` method.

Comment: While are you using `a+` mode with `foreach`? Also `open_file` is going to return the result of the last call to `.includs?` in your loop.

Comment: "not functioning" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: `a+` was amended.  `file_open` is returning white space; it should return `word` or `no match`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag my apologies.  `file_open` should return either 1. the line in the text file match the search item `word` or 2.  `no match` if `word` is not contained anywhere.  Right now `file_open` returns just white space.

Comment: Yes, `IO::foreach` always returns `nil`, the documentation says that clearly. But, you are asking about `String#include?`, what is your problem with that?

Comment: `line.include?(@word) ? "#{@word}" : "no match"` should return either the variable or the `no match` message....right now `puts x.file_open` gives me white space only.   `line.include?(@word) ? "#{@word}" : "no match"`is not being triggered in the code

Comment: Yes, `file_open` returns `nil`, because `IO::foreach` returns `nil`, just like the documentation says it does. But, you are *explicitly* asking about `include?` which has nothing to do with that particular problem in your code. It would probably be better if you removed that part of the code from your question, and focused on the part that really interests you. Read up on how to construct a [mcve], if you are not sure how to do that. At the moment, I find it hard to understand what your precise problem is, but I am confident that you could narrow it down to 2-3 lines of code.

Comment: @JörgWMittag  I know `IO` returns `nil`. My problem is `puts x.file_open` **should** trigger `.include?()` method **and** print out either my variable string if the variable string exists in `some_file.txt` or print out `no match` if my variable string does not exist in `some_file.txt`. Right now, `puts x.file_open` simply prints out white space.  **It does not provide me with the printout of the results of `.include?()`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to control the returned value. `file_open` defined above will always return `nil`. The ternary will be executed properly, but nothing is done with its value. Instead you can do the following:

```rb
class Foo
  def initialize(word)
    @word=word
  end

  def file_open
    IO.foreach('some_file.txt') do |line|
        return line if line.include?(@word)
    end
    return "no match"
  end
end
```

Comment: perhaps you can clarify. Oddily, I originally learned ternary operators as such `def a(b);b=="b" ? "foo" : "bar";end;puts a("b") => foo` w/o an explicit `return`.  Can you clarify why an explicit `return` is necessary?

Comment: Your `a` method does indeed return the result of the ternary operator. Your question is a different use case though, the ternary operator is in a loop. So even if it is evaluated as "no match", the result will be discarded because the program will just move on to the next line, until the end of the file, at which point we'll return `nil`, the value returned by `IO.foreach`. To break out of `IO.foreach`, we use what's called an early return statement. No need to check line N+1 if we found that line N matches. Also note that the last `return`, before `"no match"` is superfluous